# How to add a custom path with Laravel Twigbridge?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, twig

I'd like to add a custom directory (themes/theme_name) to Twigbridge (https://github.com/rcrowe/TwigBridge) but I'm not sure how to do this. I've read the documentation but it's not clear. Twig has the option to set 'prependPath()' or 'addPath()', but how to do this?

I tried setting the path with

```
Event::listen('twigbridge.twig', function($twig) {
    $twig->addPath( 'themes/theme_name' );
});
```

but it doesn't work.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: [http://www.slideshare.net/javier.eguiluz/twig-tips-and-tricks](http://www.slideshare.net/javier.eguiluz/twig-tips-and-tricks), frame 91

Comment: Thanks, I found that too and did the exact same thing and unfortunately it didn't work.